# Como puedo hacer funcionar el Stream con filter para fitrar en una lista segun lo que selecciones en un spinner

Tags: android, java-8

Quiero filtrar un lista según lo que seleccione en el spinner de tipo de créditos.

`listClientes` tiene la misma estructura que `listaNueva` con la clase
`ClienteRecuperacionModel`.

---

```
 public class ClienteRecuperacionModel {

     public ClienteRecuperacionModel(String codigo, 
     String documento, 
     String nombres, 
     String direccion,
     int Ntipocredito,
     int NdiasAtraso,
     boolean seleccionado) 
    {
        Codigo = codigo;
        Documento = documento;
        Nombres = nombres;
        Direccion = direccion;
        Seleccionado=seleccionado;
        ntipocredito=Ntipocredito;
        nDiasAtraso=NdiasAtraso;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return Codigo;
    }

    public String getDocumento() {
        return Documento;
    }

    public String getNombres() {
        return Nombres;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return Direccion;
    }

    public boolean isSeleccionado() {return Seleccionado;}
    public int getNtipocredito() {return ntipocredito;}

    public int getnDiasAtraso() {return nDiasAtraso;}

    private String Codigo ;

    private String Documento;

    private String Nombres ;

    private String Direccion;
    private boolean Seleccionado;
    private int ntipocredito;
    private int nDiasAtraso;
}
```

---

Asi es como lleno el ListClientes.

```
 JSONArray ListaClientesRecuperaciones = response.getJSONArray("Data");
 ClienteRecuperacionModel[] ArrayClientesRecuperaciones=gson.fromJson(ListaClientesRecuperaciones.toString(),ClienteRecuperacionModel[].class); 
 ListClientes= Arrays.asList(ArrayClientesRecuperaciones);
```

---

```
  spnTipoCredito.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TipoCreditoSel = (TipoCreditoModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                if (TipoCreditoSel.getnTipoCreditos() !=0) {
                    List<ClienteRecuperacionModel> ListaNueva = null;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        ListaNueva = ListClientes.stream().filter(x -> x.getNtipocredito()==TipoCreditoSel.getnTipoCreditos()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    }
                }

            }
```

Cuando le doy evaluate Expression a la siguente linea:

```
ListClientes.stream().filter(x->x.getNtipocredito()==TipoCreditoSel.getnTipoCreditos()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

me muestra el siguiente error.

> Error creating evaluation class loader:
>   com.intellij.debugger.engine.evaluation.EvaluateException: Method
>   threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.SO], te invito a que hagas el [tour] y de paso leas [ask] para que puedas mejorar tus preguntas, como tal tu pregunta no esta muy clara. Saludos

Comment: No describes que intentas realizar, además que es EvaluateException? agregalo por favor.

Comment: ¿Coincide la clase ClienteRecuperacionModel con el genérico del objeto ListClientes?

Comment: He replanteado la pregunta.Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Estas obligado a utilizar una expresión lambda? Si no es así prueba primero con un for para recorrer la lista y un if para la condición. Una vez hecho te será mas fácil pasarlo a una expresión lambda si lo quieres hacer así

Comment: si eso es lo que haré,realmente no estoy obligado pero que haría replicarlo asi como en C# donde a la lista le puedes hacer where.